# Is there any way to check the certificates in a client's root CA store?

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, certificate-authority

When a client connected to a web server, is there any way the check to see what root CAs the client has?

Edit: Could I use JavaScript to send a GET or POST request to the server, providing a certificate that the CA I'm checking for has to sign? If the connection fails I'll know that the root CA isn't installed on the client.

Answer (score 1):

No, the web server cannot check to see all the CA's the client has installed.

If you have access to the client machine, you can check by viewing the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the very nature of PKI (and some good system maintenance) should prevent this from being a security risk. But personally, I'm not sure I'd really want just any website to be able to enumerate my Trusted Root CA list. This sounds like a good way to phish out systems vulnerable to attacks using stuff like DigiNotar certs or certificates from other Root CA compromises.

Consider this scenario:

An attacker sends a phishing e-mail out to a bunch of users with a link to some site under the attacker's control. The site itself is generally benign, and has some minor entertainment value. But when the users visit the site, the server logs the visit and associates it with the user's e-mail address. The server then enumerates the users Trusted Root CA list, and logs if there's any CAs of interest to the attacker within that list.

Now, the attacker knows (among other things):

1. The user's e-mail account is active, and the attacker can craft an e-mail such that the user will be inclined to open it and click on a link.
2. The user's browser trusts one or more Root CAs that the attacker has deemed interesting.

The attacker could have flagged those root CAs as interesting for any number of reasons. Here's a couple:

- The attacker currently has control over the Root CA, such that he can cause it to sign arbitrary certificates generated by the attacker.
- The attacker already has some high-value certificates signed by the Root CA (either through previous control or trickery).

Now the attacker has a pool of victims which he can reasonably expect will be susceptible to phishing attacks that point the user to a website under the attacker's control. This website could present itself as a banking site, or any other site where the user might be willing to provide high-value authenticators or other useful information. The user would be likely to trust the website in doing this, because the attacker knows the browser will trust his certificate since it's signed by a "Trusted Root CA".

Since the first round of e-mails could point to a relatively benign site (i.e.: the site does not actually serve malware or steal user information), it's less likely that anyone will notice or report on it and the attacker could probably operate freely while he gathers the data for the second round.

Without information from the first round though, the second round e-mails would have to go to a much larger pool and is much more likely to catch unwanted attention due to users who are more inclined to report the attacker's e-mails than to follow its links, or users whose browsers don't trust the Root CA that signed the attacker's certificate.

The nature of PKI should generally prevent Trusted Root CA enumeration from being an issue because the attacker will still need the Root CA's private key, or a certificate signed by the Root CA, in order for that information to really be valuable. However, as exemplified by DigiNotar and others, this is not at all beyond the realm of possibility.

Updating your system will also inhibit these attacks because OS and software updates routinely include updates to the Trusted Root CA stores. This will render known-compromised Root CAs invalid to your browser, so the attacker will not be able to use their certificates to make their site look trustworthy.

Still, a threat remains to users who have not yet updated their Trusted Root CA list in the wake of a recent compromise. Even now, (2015) there's probably a number of systems which haven't yet received updates to remove DigiNotar (2011), because of lax maintenance practices.

So, while proper security precautions and system maintenance will prevent Trusted Root CA enumeration from being of much value to an attacker in most scenarios, it's still not something you want your browser to just hand over to anyone.

All that said, I don't know personally whether there is or isn't a way to do this - it just seems like A Bad Idea™ to me.

Comment: One other potential issue is the identification of users.  While the list of trusted roots could be valuable for fingerprinting, far more worrisome would be the ability to identify individual clients with specific private trusted root certs as belonging to a specific organization and network.

Comment: @Xander Good point - putting an even sharper "spear" in "spear phishing".

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: Could I use JavaScript to send a GET or POST request to the server, providing a certificate that the CA I'm checking for has to sign? If the connection fails I'll know that the root CA isn't installed on the client.

That's probably the best thing you could do. You still can get false negatives if the TLS handshake fails for some other reason (which is unlikely if you use the same server with the same configuration all the time). You will get wrong information if the client is behind some TLS interception device/proxy (like firewalls or the infamous [SuperFish](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/02/ssl-busting-code-that-threatened-lenovo-users-found-in-a-dozen-more-apps/)), because then you will get all the CAs accepted by this device/proxy and not by the browser itself.